# How to list column values with matching name on excel?

Tags: excel-formula

Let's say I have many labelers with `Pass` values.

```
   (A)           (B) 
   Labelers      Pass
   _________     ___
4  Labeler X1A   111
5  Labeler O2A   62
6  Labeler R1    61
7  Labeler O1B   60
8  Labeler R2A   49
9  Labeler A1    10
...
60 Labeler Y1    29
```

I need to fill the table below with the sum of the matching values above. In short, I expect value of `10` to be on `Total Pass` for `Labeler A1`. The formula will go under `Total Pass`, next to Labelers. The formula will look at the "name" of Labeler (i.e., `Labeler A1`), scans the above table, when it sees `"Labeler A1"`, it will pass the value of `10` from the table above to the table below.

```
   (A)         (B)
   Labeler     Total Pass
   __________  __________
63 Labeler A1
64 Labeler A2
65 Labeler A3
66 Labeler A4
67 Labeler A5
68 Labeler A6 
69 Labeler A7
...
```

I have tried `SUMIF` function `=SUMIF(A4:A60,"=A63",B4:B60)`, whereas `A4:A60` is the range of Labelers on the first table, `A63` is the cell of `Labeler A1`, and `B4:B60` is the first table's `Pass` column but it returns 0.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: just want to clarify your example data.  the number in the front of labeler are row numbers?  and the A in front of Labeler is supposed to mean the labeller is column A?

Comment: Correct. I added them for reference. A 1 2 3 4... column is the excel column/row, for visual aid purpose. Hope that doesn't make it more confusing!

Comment: Does the name in column A appear more than once or is it unique?  I am trying to figure out if you are adding all the results from the same names, or just trying to find the one result from the unique name.  Its the difference between using SUMIF or VLOOKUP,INDEX/MATCH options

Comment: Sorry for late reply! Column A is unique. There will only be one instance of, say, `Labeler A1` in the entire column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, from 63 to 119 are the rows where you want to sum up the values that occur in the rows 4 to 60.  If that is the case, in B63 use the following formula and copy down:

```
=SUMIF($A$4:$A$60,$A63,$B$4:$B$60)
```